# Swift 2.2: #if swift(>=x.y) version build configuration: can it be used to check sub-versions? (E.g. distinguish Swift 2.1 from 2.1.1)

Tags: swift2

With Swift 2.2, we can now make use of the `#if swift(>=x.y)` version build configuration, [as proposed in SE-0020 of Swift evolution](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0020-if-swift-version.md).

```
#if swift(>=2.2)
  print("Active!")
#else
  this! code! will! not! parse! or! produce! diagnostics!
#endif
```

I've tried, *out of curiosity*, to attempt to use this with one step lower subversion level comparison (say `>=2.1.1` without passing Swift `2.1` from XCode 7.1 beta 2), but my own attempts don't really work:

- `>=x.y.z` yields an error,

  > *expected named member of numeric literal*
- `>=x.y` with `y = 11` naturally compiles and passes but as a version we're yet to see, `2.11`.

I can't find any further details regarding this in the [XCode 7.3 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html).

**Question:** Is this new version build configuration limited to a single `.y` subversion, or is there some trick to circumvent this?

Comment: from your link .... "For now, we'll only expect up to two version components, since it will be unlikely that a syntax change will make it in a +0.0.1 revision."      two version components only is the answer

Comment: @user3441734 jeez, I totally missed that, thanks! (Feel free to add as an answer)

Comment: @user3441734 I also now found [this post from the Swift evolution thread](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151214/003455.html), where Douglas Gregor writes _"Two levels of version number should be sufficient."_, as an acceptable side effect of using a floating point literal in the `#if swift(>= ....)` signature (rather than, say, a string, `"2.1.1"`). So it seems that the limitation of two version components wasn't an active choice (an effect), but rather one of convenience, w.r.t. comparing floating point literals rather than string literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:** The new version build configuration is limited to two version components.

---

From [Swift Evolution, proposal SE-0020: Swift Language Version Build Configuration](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0020-if-swift-version.md)

> **Detailed design**
>
> ...
>
> For now, we'll only expect up to two version components, since it will
>   be unlikely that a syntax change will make it in a +0.0.1 revision.

More details can be found in [the associated Swift Evolution thread](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151214/003455.html), most specifically in this exchange between Chris Lattner and Douglas Gregor:

> *On Dec 18, 2015, at 3:34 PM, Douglas Gregor via swift-evolution  wrote:*
>
> ...
>
> > *On Dec 18, 2015, at 12:29 PM, Chris Lattner via swift-evolution  wrote:*
> >
> > ...
> >
> > The argument to use a string is **if we wanted to support subversions**, e.g. like “#if swift(2.2.1)”.  This requires the parameter to be a string, **because 2.2.1 isn’t a valid floating point literal** - the lexer will be displeased.
>
> ...
>
> This feature LGTM, and I also prefer that we drop the quotes. 
>   **Two levels of version number should be sufficient**.